# Magento import or export a products value rather than it's label

Tags: magento

How can I import and export a products value instead of its label. When importing of exporting products from Magento, it is the attributes label that is used, not the value.

The colour attribute is an example of this behaviour, when selecting the colour attribute for a product, the drop down contains labels, strings of colour names eg "red", "blue" etc, but the values are integers, eg 26, 25 etc. When exporting products, the colour field in the CSV list contains the string value, not the integer. And when importing products Magento expects the colour field to contain a string, not an integer.

Is there a class I can override such that I can change the behaviour for a particular attribute giving me control of what data is imported or exported for one particular attribute. The attribute is not a standard Magento attribute, but one that I've added myself.

Thanks